# GUI for home automation project using Raspberry and arduino

Tags: user-interface, arduino, raspberry-pi, home-automation

I am working on a home automation project which involves a raspberry pi connected to arduino via I2C, and the arduino controls the 8 channel relay.

Can some one suggest me some of the user interface which I can create on raspberry pi to control the arduino.

I have done few research online came across Tkinter, OpenHab, PubNub and few more.
I am looking for a GUI in which has attractive user appeal.

any help would be great, please understand I am just a beginner.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned Tkinter I assuming you are willing to use Python as programming language in the Raspberry Pi side. Although Tkinter is easy, the graphical interfaces that you can create with this library are not so user appealing in my opinion. A better alternative could be the [pyGTK library](http://www.pygtk.org/) that is easy to use and learn. If you decided to go for it, I recommend that you follow [this tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/unstable/tutorial.py.html.en) specially designed for beginners.